# Understanding CREATE CONTRACT in an airgapped network

Tags: sql-server, database

We have an airgapped network - not connected to the internet. I was parsing through some code our IDAM vendor sent and it is using the CREATE CONTRACT function (not a db engineer). I looked at the documentation provided by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-contract-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and I still don't quite understand it.

I've looked at the documentation provided by Microsoft and I still don't understand the function of CREATE CONTRACT. How will this be affected in an airgapped network?

```
CREATE CONTRACT [//PGScheduledJobContract]
    ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer] SENT BY INITIATOR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Service Broker is an in-database message queuing feature of SQL Server.

A Service Broker contract defines the messages that may be exchanged between two Service Broker Services.  That contract specifies that a particular [message type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-message-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will be sent by the initiator service.

The message type is named with a URI just because it's a built-in message type shipped by Microsoft.  SQL Server does not need to contact that URI at runtime.